# don't keep super class's public method in proguard

Tags: proguard

I have class A , and class B extends class A. 
My proguard config is :

```
-keep public class  B {
    public  <methods>;
}
```

I just want to keep the public methods in B , but proguard keep the public methods in A too.

Does anyone know how to reslove it ?

thanks ~

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to enumerate the methods. Semantically, public methods of super classes are public methods in their subclasses too, so ProGuard keeps them if you use a wildcard..